# How to list completion options of a command via bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line, autocomplete

All right, I'm aware about how to provide [a custom completion function to a command](https://askubuntu.com/a/483149/689894). And I also know this options can be printed out in a shell session by double hit <kbd>tab</kbd> after write that command.

I'm now looking for a way to list the completion options of a given command via bash script.
I mean some command that do the same behavior of tap <kbd>tab</kbd> twice

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

`complete -p command` gives you the information what would be done. You can do that on your own.

That seems not to work with functions which use `compopt` (without a command name). Maybe the mode of operation can be faked somehow. Or you could try writing a function for `compopt` which adds the name.