# how to output all possibilities in linux without tab?

Tags: linux

I'm a linux beginner

I want to filter the possibilities in of a linux command ,
for example , how can i output the possibilities of 'service'?

I hope that was clear enough

thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "output the possibilities of service"?

Comment: You could use the MAN pages, example
'man service'

Comment: You say "without tab", so are you referring to the list of possible [completions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion) generated by your shell (e.g., Bash) when you enter a command and press ``TAB`` twice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List all commands that a shell knows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94775/list-all-commands-that-a-shell-knows)

Comment: @amadeusamadeus yes exactly what you said , I'm sorry if I was not clear enough.
I could not find it with 'man service'.

Comment: Most commands have a `--help` option that should give you an overview of their invocation. Now, `service` is a bit special, as the man page says: "The supported values of COMMAND depend on the invoked script". This is so because `service` invokes a script which may have many different options that `service` know nothing about. Whether the script itself has a help function depends on the script as well.

Comment: @ARIK So you are talking about the *arguments* the shell suggests for completion, while people commenting about *man* and ```--help``` think you would be talking about the *options* of a command. Can you relate to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581679/)?